# Take two variables from a message and put each into different parts

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command in `discord.js`.

I want to make it where `?party (link or something here) requirements: be cool` is typed and then it would say

> @user has pinged for party Link: (link that was posted) requirements:
> be cool

I'm new to `discord.js` so I'm trying to learn. Thank You!

Comment: So…you want, `?party (link or something here) ` and `requirments: be cool` to be 2 different commands?

Comment: I want it to take the link part and the requirement part (in the same command) but then put them into different parts of the returning message. Example:
@user started a party

Link: (the link part of the command here)

Requirements: (the requirements part of the command here)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @skara9 | if(message.content.startsWith("*party")) {
  let link = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
  if(!link) link = "no link"
  let req = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ")
  if(!req) req = "no req"
  else {
    message.channel.send(`has pinged for party\n \nLink: ${link}\n \nRequirements: ${req}\n \n@everyone`)
  }
} | its a hot mess of garbage

Comment: @user17758804 don't post code in comments, just update your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, prolly change you command to be something like:

`?party (link) (be cool)`. Keep things simple :)

Then you could parse thru the contents of the command and separate out the link from the requirements, like so:

```
text = message.content;

// check if the text is a command for your bot
if (text.startsWith("?party")) {
  // convert the contents of the command to an array, by splitting the text at spaces
  // Also get the rid of the command itself (?party)
  commandContents = text.split(" ").slice(1);
  link = commandContents[0];
  requirements = commandContents.slice(1).join(" "); // join the requirements back by spaces.

  if (!link) {
    message.channel.send(" no link");
  } else if (!requirements) {
    message.channel.send(" no requirements");
  } else {
    message.channel.send(
      `<@${message.author.id}> has pinged for party\n \n Link: ${link}]\n\nRequirements:${requirements}\n\n@everyone`
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Also a hot mess of garbage, but hopefully will work for you :)

Comment: made a few adjustments and it works smoothly! just one question, how can i make it ping the person who executed the command?

Comment: you could use `message.reply` instead of `message.channel.send`, or if you wish to have an @mention, then you could get the id of the user by `message.author.id`. Updated my answer to mention the author :)